# Error when using R to get credentials from Windows Cred Vault

Tags: r, windows, postgresql, credentials

I receive the following error...

```
Error in b_wincred_i_get(target) : 
Windows credential store error in 'get': Element not found.
```

...when running the following script in R v3.5.1 (R Studio v1.1.456) and keyring v1.1.0. I'm attempting this on a new setup so not sure if this could be as simple as a firewall issue or the like. The script errors out when attempting to get the password (`key_get(json_data$service, json_data$user)`). I've tried manually plugging in the service and username into the `key_get` method (instead of using the variables from the config file) but get the same error. The config file is a json file that holds all of the connection details except the password, which obviously gets retrieved from the Windows Credentials Vault. Any help in figuring out a fix for this is greatly appreciated.

```
library(RJDBC)
library(keyring)
library(jsonlite)

postgres.connection <- function(json_data){

  print("Creating Postgres driver...")
  pDriver <- JDBC(driverClass=json_data$driver, classPath="C:/Users/Drivers/postgresql-42.2.4.jar")

  print("Connecting to Postgres...")
  server <- paste("jdbc:postgresql://", json_data$host, ":", json_data$port, "/", json_data$dbname, sep="")
  pConn <- dbConnect(pDriver, server, json_data$user, key_get(json_data$service, json_data$user))

  return(pConn)

}

json_data <- fromJSON("C:/Users/Configs/Config.json", simplifyVector = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
json_data_connection <- json_data$postgres$local_read
pc <- postgres.connection(json_data_connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it's a new setup. Is the password already in credentials? To check, go to 'Control Panel'>'User Accounts'>'Credential Manager'>'Windows Credentials', is it under 'Generic Credentials'?
I can get the same error by running:
`key_get('not-valid-service', 'some-user')`

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but given that I recently encountered the same problem on windows and Google let me here...

The keyring package appears to assume the credentials to be stored in a very specific format, e.g. `:service:username` filled in the field that the windows credential manager calls "internet or network address". Not that this might not be the case if you fill in your credentials manually into the windows credential manager, but if you use the function `key_set_with_value` from the `keyring` package, then the credentials get stored in the format expected by the keyring package.